# I am getting "Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream" in Azure pipeline step

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, azure-pipelines

I am running the following `-bash` command:

- bash: $(ci_scripts_path)/01_install_python_tools.sh
  displayName: 'Install python 2.7 tools'
  failOnStderr: true

while the sh script `01_install_python_tools.sh` completes successfully, but anyhow I get this error for the step:
`##[error]Bash wrote one or more lines to the standard error stream.`

Answer (score 2):

I was just dealing with this today and was able to resolve it by unchecking *'Fail on Standard Error'* in the Advanced options of the Bash task. The step will still fail if your script returns a non-zero exit code, but will succeed if you return 0.

So, if I want to return a success I have the script `exit 0`
If I want to throw an error, I'll do an `exit 1`. For example, I have a script that does something like this:

```
if [ "$someResult" == "yay it worked" ] then
    echo "Success!"
    exit 0
else
    echo "Failsauce!"
    exit 1
fi
```

I was thinking for a long time that I must have that option enabled to be able to return a failure into the pipeline, but it isn't the case apparently.

Comment: Thanks for this hint. I've added "set -e" to stop in case of any error during the script run and switched off this tick.